# Why do we need to use @ViewChild to call function of a component from other component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-components, viewchild

My tutor told me that, "In angular we can use function defined in any service by just importing that service but we can't import a component in any other component. To use function defined in any other component we need to use @ViewChild(ComponentName)."

But when I tried to call function of a component in other component without using @viewChild, I was successful and there was not any error occurred.

Please refer the below example to understand the scenario:

**CASE1: Calling function of a component in other component without using @ViewChild**

Suppose we have a component "testcomponent" and in that component we have a "hello" function as below:

testcomponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ContentChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testcomponent',
  templateUrl: './testcomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testcomponent.component.css']
})
export class TestcomponentComponent implements {
  constructor(){}

  hello(){
    console.log("Hello ABC");
  }
}
```

To use the "hello" function of "testcomponent" component in "app" component, I tried the following:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { TestcomponentComponent } from './testcomponent/testcomponent.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  constructor(private testcomponent : TestcomponentComponent ){};

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.testComponent.hello();
  }
}
```

Here "Hello ABC" get printed in the console and there was not any error occurred.

**CASE2: Calling function of a component in other component with using @ViewChild**

Now consider the case when I used @ViewChild in "app.component.ts" file to call "hello()" function of "testcomponent" component:

```
  import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';


  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChild(TestcomponentComponent,{static:false}) viewChildOnComponentSelector : TestcomponentComponent;


    ngAfterViewInit(){

      this.viewChildOnComponentSelector.hello();
    }

  }
```

Since in CASE1 I was able to call "hello()" method of "testcomponent" in "app" component, then why we need @ViewChild as in CASE2?

Also please explain me, if we can call function of any component in any other component by just importing that component (as in CASE1) , then what is the difference in calling a function of a Component or a Service?

Answer (score 2):

When you inject in constructor a service, this is a service unique. If you inject a component only inject a "copy", NOT the component you're seeing, e.g. if your component has a input with a [(ngModel)] you never could reach the value of the input.

this is the reason because it's not considered a good aproach inject a component (if we only has access to a functions, why not use a simple class?)

NOTE: If you call is using a button in .html, you can simple use a variable reference, e.g, your main-component is like:

```
<button (click)="child.hello()">click</button>
<app-child-component #child></app-child-component>
```